# Custom QueryParameters values with SpringQueryMap and OpenFeign

Tags: spring-boot

Is there a way for sending custom query parameters using @SpringQueryMap annotation together with OpenFeign? Here's an example:

```
public class PersonStatus {`
  @JsonProperty("person.active=true")
  String isActive;
  @JsonProperty("person.active=false")
  String isNotActive;
}`
```

Where in the OpenFeign call, we invoke this way:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/active", consumes = "application/json")
ResponseEntity<List<Person>> queryProductRecommendation(@SpringQueryMap PersonStatus personStatus);
```

However when i check my invocations, I can see that the query parameter name that is being set is the attribute's name (isActive) and not the custom name of the attribute (person.active=true).

Answer (score 1):

Use @feign.Param on get method:

```java
import feign.Param;
public class PersonStatus {
    String isActive;
    String isNotActive;
    @Param("person.active=true")
    public String getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }
    @Param("person.active=false")
    public String getIsNotActive() {
        return isNotActive;
    }
}
```

In default configuration of spring boot, object annotated with @SpringQueryMap is encoded by BeanQueryMapEncoder, while BeanQueryMapEncoder only read @Param annotaion on methods.

If you use lombok fot getters, you can use onMethod property in @Getter. Read @Getter doc before use:

```java
import feign.Param;
import lombok.Getter;
public class PersonStatus {
    @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Param("person.active=true")})
    String isActive;
    @Getter(onMethod_ = {@Param("person.active=false")})
    String isNotActive;
}
```